# What does the superiority of bani-Israel (Children of Israel) over all beings mean?

Tags: tafseer, ahlul-kitab, bani-israel, surat-al-baqarah

I read in some different surahs of Quran  mentioning the superiority  of bani-Israeli  over all beings. What is true interpretation of these verses?

> يَا بَنِي إِسْرَ‌ائِيلَ اذْكُرُ‌وا نِعْمَتِيَ الَّتِي أَنْعَمْتُ
> عَلَيْكُمْ وَأَنِّي فَضَّلْتُكُمْ عَلَى الْعَالَمِينَ
>
> Children of Israel, remember My blessing wherewith I blessed you, and that I have preferred you above all beings;

[Surah al-Baqarah Verse 47](http://quran.com/2/47)

Answer (score 6):

They were preferred or made superior because they embraced religion and followed the Divine Prophets while other people lived in misled and ignorance. But once they started to misbehave by disobeying their Prophets and compromising their religion they instead invited God's wrath and condemnation. This is apparent in several Qur’anic verses condemning Jews for their disobedience of God, betraying their Prophets and developing false beliefs about God, like the belief that "God's hand is tied up" [(5:64)](http://tanzil.net/#trans/en.itani/5:64), meaning that He cannot abolish His previous decrees.

Therefore the Divine preference of Jews was neither exclusive nor unconditional. As Allah says: "The best among you in the sight of Allah is the most righteous." [(49:13)](http://tanzil.net/#trans/en.sahih/49:13). The statement is general and hence applies to every group of people who embrace religion and follow it sincerely, and is consequently revoked once they compromise their commitment. So Jews have no inherent superiority over humankind, nor did they live up to the virtues that once qualified them for Divine preference.

Answer (score 1):

Allah (SWT) also sent most of the prophets among the Bani Israel. They are called "The Chosen Ones" in the Holy Quran.

Answer (score 1):

The children of Israel did not only believe in Allah but they also entered into a covenant relationship with Allah. The book and the prophethood was given to the seed of Yaqub (jacob). The Covenant and promises of the covenant were given to Abrahim then ishaq (isaac) then it (the covenant inheritance, birth right) was passed to Yaqub (jacob) whom was renamed as Israel and from jacob the inheritance was passed to his 12sons whom became 12tribes (children of israel). Bani Israil (the children of Israel) experienced great salvation from Allah (the plagues in egypt, the red sea split before them that they may walk through as on dry land, The fire of Allah came down on Mt. Sinai and he spoke to them as a nation from the fire) no other nation has Allah done such things as this.

In the covenant of Allah with Bani Israel there was supreme blessings if they obeyed but curses if the rebelled and worshiped strange gods.

Read deuteronomy 28 in Torah (bible)

They went astray and were exiled out of the holy land of Israel and went into middle east and great majority went south into Africa and interior of Africa and were sold into slavery as it was prophecied by prophet musa (moses) in deuteronomy 28.

Answer (score 0):

The covenant is when Allah agreed with the bani Israil that all decedents of Adam must follow and worship him. In return Allah will give them a blessing.

Comment: Welcome to Islam SE. Answers should be elaborate and focused on addressing the question. Claims should be supported by evidence. Please visit our [tour] in the [help], and refer to [answer].