# In what way and why did Allah give special favours to Bani Israel?

Tags: prophets, bani-israel

According to Qur'an, Allah gave many special favours to Bani Israel.

In what way did he favour them?

What was the reason for this?

How is different from the prophets he sent to the rest of mankind that we don't know the names of?

Also, given the above, why would Muhammad (peace) not be sent to the people Allah had already given so much to given the importance of Muhammad above all prophets?

(Here the Christian claims that Israel was specifically chosen and prepared for the saving work which could then after Jesus be spread to the rest of mankind who never received the call to God. What is Islamic response to this?)

Comment: Related: http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/16422/

Comment: I have lack of knowledge about this but in my view I think Quran only explain the favor given to israel due to they have close relation to arabs and Allah want to remind jews what he have given to them. Allah have given favor to ever nation but only discuss the favor of jews and the nation near to arab.

Comment: Israel is different of Bani Israel

Comment: "How is ...different from the prophets he sent" fill in the gap please...

Answer (score 3):

I think you are referring to the Verse 47 in Surat al-Baqara (2:47)

> O Children of Israel! Just recall to mind My favor that bestowed upon
>   you, and remember that I exalted you above all the peoples of the
>   world

First i think the Verses 40 -120 of the same Sura seem to explain this very clearly how Allah gave them favors and forgave their disbelieve and how Allah saved them from Pharao and after that when Musa (peace be upon him) was invited and they turn to worship a calf in his absence ...

But lets try to explain it with other Verses from the Quran: First of all the favors of Allah is very much as you find in Surat Ibrahim (14:34)

> It is He Who fulfilled all your requirements; so much so that you
>   cannot count His bounties, if you tried to number them. The fact is
>   that man is very unjust and ungrateful.

And their Messenger and Prophet Musa (peace be upon him) called them to mind about some of them as we can read in Surat al Ma'ida (5:20)

> Call to mind the time when Moses said to his people, "O my people,
>   remember the favor which Allah bestowed upon you. He raised up
>   Prophets from among you and made you rulers and gave you that which
>   had not been given to anyone in the world.

In this Verse Allah reveals religious favors (Prophets) and material favors.

But this was when they where good people (ibad Allah a-Salhyn) as it is explained in Surat al-I'mran (3:110) and (3:112) they fell in disgrace

> Now you are the best community which has been raised up for the
>   guidance of mankind: you enjoin what is right and forbid what is
>   wrong and believe in Allah. Had these people of the Book also
>   believed, it would have surely been better for them (110).
>
> ...
>
> Disgrace and humiliation have been stamped upon them wherever they may
>   be except in the case when they get refuge under the favor of Allah
>   or under the patronage of other people. They have incurred the wrath
>   of Allah; therefore misery and humiliation have been stamped upon
>   them. This is because they rejected the Revelations of Allah and
>   killed His Prophets without any just cause; this is the consequence of
>   their disobedience and their transgression.(112)

Comment: how would you comment the fact that founders of google and facebook (which have very many users, like almost all, or more than half, of all computer users) are jews? is not it some sign of power of jewish community?

Answer (score 2):

This [answer](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/16424/11938) to the question [What does the superiority of bani-israel (Children of Israel) over all beings mean?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/16422/what-does-the-superiority-of-bani-israel-children-of-israel-over-all-beings-me) answers some aspects of the question above. But still I would like to answer the following in detail.

---

> O Children of Israel! Remember **My (Allah's) favour** wherewith I favoured you and how I preferred you to (all) creatures. (Qur'an 2:122)

So, **the children of Israel and Allah know better what was the favour being discussed above.**

But, we can guess. Many places in Qur'an Allah was talking about the following keywords "children of israel", "favour", "covenant", "broke the covenant"... So, we can find that there is some link among each other.

First, of all, the **main favour of Allah upon them(although not specifically mentioned) is the gifting of Torah and Injeel(Gospels given to Jesus(pbuh)).** And then about the covenant.

> O Children of Israel! call to mind the (special) favour which I bestowed upon you, and fulfil your covenant with Me as I fulfil My Covenant with you, and fear none but Me. (Qur'an 2:40)

And the verses Qur'an [2:63](http://quran.com/2/63) and [2:83](http://quran.com/2/83) talk further about the covenant. So to conlude this part, ask specifically to the Children of Israel(concerning the above keywords discussed), what all favours God made to them. But before you ask, a small reminder.

> **And if you should count the favors of Allah , you could not enumerate them.** Indeed, Allah is Forgiving and Merciful. (Qur'an 16:18)

---

> ..different from the prophets he sent to the rest of mankind that we don't know the names of?

Allah [sent messengers to every nation](http://quran.com/10/47) thereby favoring upon his grace to every nation by sending those prophets that we don't know the names of. But, just because they're not made examples set for us in the scriptures doesn't imply the favor made by Allah to them is either less or more.

---

> why would Muhammad (peace be upon him) not be sent to the people Allah had already given so much to given the importance of Muhammad above all prophets?

The creator had his own reasons so as where to send Prophet Muhammad(pbuh). One simple reason is that God had to favor the Arab nation too as he favored the Children of Israel. ([Qur'an 3:164](http://quran.com/3/164))

---

> Here the Christian claims that Israel was specifically chosen and prepared for the saving work which could then after Jesus be spread to the rest of mankind who never received the call to God. What is Islamic response to this?

I'm sorry, but there are verses which show Prophet Jesus(pbuh) of Nazareth was sent specifically(or only) to the lost sheep among the children of Israel. And he in turn commanded his disciples to do the same.

> Go rather to the lost sheep of Israel. ([Mat 10:6](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Mat%2010&version=NIV))

(Although I cherry picked no where did Jesus(pbuh) said go to the whole world).

May the creator guide us all.

Answer (score 0):

I will be updating the below with references with time so please do not down vote for this.

Allah (sbhwta) sent messengers to every nation but he only sent messengers with scripture to Ibrahim (Abraham) (pbuh) and his descendants.  Without scripture, the message from the messengers can be distorted and forgotten with time.  This was Allah's promise to Ibrahim (pbuh) and Allah keeps his promise.

The Quran mentions the following prophets (pbut) who have received scripture:

**Ibrahim**  87:19, 53:37

**Musa** (Moshe, Moses) received **Tawra** (Torah, Pentateuch)  5:44

**Dawood** (David) received **Zabur** (Psalms)  4:164, 17:55, 21:105

**Eisa ibn Merriam** (Yeshua, Jesus) received **Injeel** (Gospel) 5:36

**Muhammed** (final messenger)  received **Quran**  76:23

Musa, Dawood, and Eisa ibn Merriem (pbut) are all descendants of **Israel** or **Yakoob** (Yakov, Jacob)(pbuh).  Thus the term **Bani Israel** (sons of, descendants of Israel).  Israel (pbuh) was the son of **Ishak** (Isaac) (pbuh) who was the younger son of Ibrahim (pbuh).  **Muhammed** (pbuh) and his Hashemite line descended from **Ismail** (Ishmael) (pbuh) older son of Ibrahim (pbuh).

Without even considering the numerous prophets and their texts included in the old testament, we see that all but the book of Ibrahim and the Quran were sent to Bani Israel.  This fact alone explains the very special favor by Allah to the Bani Israel.